# Getting error of invalid arguments when I try to compare two lists using SequenceEqual or Except function in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting error of invalid arguments when I try to compare two lists using SequenceEqual or Except function in Linq using C# code. My code is as follow,

```
var one = db.arabia_upod_item_availability_masters.ToList();
var two = db.vw_get_arabia_upod_report_quantityOrderedPerItem_uhjs.ToList();
var result = one.SequenceEqual(two).ToString();
```

It is same for Except function also. But in both case I get error. Why is it so? What can be the solution?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `one` and `two` should be the same types. As you get them from a `db`, which I assume is a context, I can hardly imagine that they are the same type. You probably should project to some common denominator first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) and [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) throw ArgumentNullException, Possibly either (or both) of your lists `one` or `two` is null.

You may check prior to using SequenceEqual.

```
if(one != null && two != null)
   {
      var result = one.SequenceEqual(two).ToString();
   }
else
   {
      //null 
   }
```

Comment: I am getting the error in the code itself. It is 'list does not the definition for SequenceEqual... and invalid arguments...'

Comment: @JavedAhmed, you mean, you can't compile the code ? do you have `using System.Linq;` at the top ?